# Get dynamic route parameter value in app-component and add it to every route of the app in Angular 12

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

In my Angular 12 app, I have a requirement to extract value of a route parameter when the app loads and add it to every route in the app. The user of the app will be sent a URL like https://testdomain.blah/car/welcome. Now the value 'car' in the route is dynamic. It can be 'bus', 'bike'. etc. I have to pick up that value in the app-component and add it to each route in the app. So when the user navigates to another route like details for example, the URL should be https://testdomain.blah/car/details/uid

The routes defined in app-routing.module.ts file are

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {
    path: ':type',
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'welcome',
            pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {
            path: 'welcome',
            loadChildren: () => import('./welcome/welcome.module').then(m => m.WelcomeModule)
        },
        {
            path: 'details/:uid',
            loadChildren: () => import('./details/details.module').then(m => m.DetailsModule)
        },
        {
            path: '**',
            redirectTo: 'welcome',
            pathMatch: 'full'
        }
    ]
 }
];
```

I am trying to fetch the dynamic route parameter value in app.component.ts file as shown below

```
this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
        console.log(params.get("type"));
    });
```

But null value is logged in console. So I am not able to get that 'car' value in the app component. I couldn't figure out what is causing this issue and how to add this parameter to every route in the app. Please help me out with this.

Comment: Are you getting the params if you `console.log(params);`
First check if you are getting params at all or not? Comment after checking, we can discuss then

Comment: Yes I tried console.log(params) but not getting params at all.

Comment: Just do one thing. instead of paramMap only do params. like `activatedRoute.params.subscribe`

Comment: Tried it. Still not getting any params

Comment: Then this will work. Go to your respective components, like welcome and details and then call `activatedRoute.parent.params.subscribe`. You will get the parent param. Check it and let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are dependent on AppComponent which is the root component also, for your use case, you will need to have a separate root component, which will display AppComponent and then AppComponent can listen to params:

create a wrapper root component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'root',
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
})
export class RootComponent {
  constructor() {  }
}
```

modify your index.html to remove your app component selector and use this:

```
<root>Loading...</root>
```

Then modify the routing to include AppComponent:

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {
    path: ':type',
    component: AppComponent
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'welcome',
            pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {
            path: 'welcome',
            loadChildren: () => import('./welcome/welcome.module').then(m => m.WelcomeModule)
        },
        {
            path: 'details/:uid',
            loadChildren: () => import('./details/details.module').then(m => m.DetailsModule)
        },
        {
            path: '**',
            redirectTo: 'welcome',
            pathMatch: 'full'
        }
    ]
 }
```

Modify your app module to bootstrap Root component:

```
 declarations: [AppComponent, RootComponent],
 bootstrap: [RootComponent]
```

Now your activate route subscription should work.

Comment: Yup. This approach worked. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Glad that it worked :)